# создание своего тэга <calculator> в html используя javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, ctags

Можете помочь? У меня есть калькулятор на Javascript. Мне нужно создать свой тэг, при добавлении которого появлялся мой калькулятор?

Comment: тэг калькулятора? Кажется я что-то не знаю о веб-технологиях.

Comment: тоже не представляю о чем идёт речь в принципе.

Comment: Опишите поподробнее что вам нужно сделать.

Comment: Это что-то типа React компонента уже)

Comment: Так, вторая попытка) Покажите код вашего калькулятора)

Comment: Если вам просто для расширения кругозора, то вот вам экспериментальная технология - (https://learn.javascript.ru/webcomponent-core). Если для работы, то вот вам более полезная ссылка для создания своих приложений - (https://learn.javascript.ru/prototypes).

Comment: Скорее не тэг калькулятора, а тэг с кастомным названием. Можно создать хоть чёрта лысого, описать его стилями и скриптами, но вот не проще ли использовать для этого div с классами?

Answer (score 3):

Примерно так:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('calculator').show(function() {
    myCalc.init(this);

  })
});

var myCalc = new Object();
myCalc.params = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2
};
myCalc.init = function(container) {
  layout = "<div id='calc'><input type='text' id='in'><br>";
  layout += "<span id='out'><br>";
  layout += "<button id='plus'>+</button>&nbsp;<button id='minus'>-</button>&nbsp;<button id='eq'>=</button></div>";
  $(container).append(layout);
}
```

```css
calculator {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<calculator>
  my calc
</calculator>
```